# How to not fail build on an unresolvable dependency with Gradle - Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-library

I am constructing a mutli-module library for Android using AS and Gradle. Each module is published to an Artifactory repo independently but in sync as a complete version number with each module having the same version number (e.g. full library version is 1.2.1 then each module is republished as 1.2.1 for that release to stay in sync).

The issue is that I am trying to automate the release build and publication of all of these libraries in unison with Gradle but each module relies on a 'core' module which holds the shared logic. The issue arises when I try to create these gradle build tasks with the core module as a provided dependency e.g.:

`provided 'xyz.abc.mylib-core:' + version`

Where version is the shared release version. I have made a gradle task which performs each step of the cleaning, release build, test and publication of each library like so:

`task artifactoryPublishMyLibCore(dependsOn: [':mylib-core:clean',
      ':mylib-core:test',
      ':mylib-core:jacocoTestReport',
      ':mylib-core:sonarRunner',
      ':mylib-core:assembleRelease',
      ':mylib-core:artifactoryPublish'])
task artifactoryPublishMyLibModule1(dependsOn:
        ['artifactoryPublishMyLibCore', ':mylib-module1:clean',
         ':mylib-module1:test',
         ':mylib-module1:jacocoTestReport',
         ':mylib-module1:sonarRunner',
         ':mylib-module1:assembleRelease',
         ':mylib-module1:artifactoryPublish'
        ])`

Now the problem comes when trying to sync gradle

`Error:Failed to resolve: xyz.abc.mylib-core:1.2.1`

Which is fair enough as at this point the library will not have been published but when the build task is run it will be published by the time it is required and also I am using core as a 'provided' runtime dependency in each of the modules so it is not required (as far as I know) to compile each module.

Am I missing something obvious here and if not is there a way to:

1. Not fail the build when a runtime dependency cannot resolve?

or

2. Stub the dependency that gradle cannot resolve for the sync as it will be available when the actual compile occurs on the modules?

Any and all help appreciated.

Edit: Note that this is not an issue for debugging as I use the modules are included as project dependencies when doing a debugCompile it is only when trying to do the release where the dependencies must be properly referenced for the Artifactory.

Comment: You have library core which is build with Library B. But B has a reference to core. Why? That smells really bad.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. So for a little more context in this scenario I am building a library which allows the use of modular providers to a proprietary service. Core contains the logic for interaction with the apps and the providers results. Each provider module may or may not be contained in a localised version of the app but without core the providers are useless so core is included as a runtime dependency within each provider module (interfaces to interact with core etc.). Is this a glaring error? If so could you please expand?

Comment: Sorry, I got your question wrong the first time I read it. So the problem is that you try to pull the current core version from the artifactory repo but can't because it gets published as soon as core and the other modules have been build. Which they can't because core hasn't been published yet.

Comment: Yes so I'm trying to automate the process of building a publishing them in sequence but the error arises on gradle sync so the build task cannot be initiated. When the task is executed it would look like:


build core -> publish core -> build module (with published core) -> publish module -> repeat for each module


But gradle will not allow a sync when a reference to an unpublished library is present (in this case, the core reference in the module)


Is there any way around this?